# Firefox gives Network Error whereas other browsers work just fine (ReactJS App)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, browser, axios

I made a web app using React.js and Im making calls to the backend through Axios.

However, Firefox keeps giving me a Network error when awaiting a response from the Server. Other browsers such as Chrome, Safari, Opera work just fine.

Code for the request:

```
export function postLoginDetails(username, password, token) {
const url = ENV.host + "/login";

return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": token
    },
    data: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    },
    responseType: 'json'
   }).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Heres the code where the error occurs: res is undefined.

```
postLoginDetails(username, password, this.token).then((res) => {
                if (res.data.success) {
                    this.isAuthenticated.set(true)
                    cb();
                } else {
                    this.error.set(true);
                    this.errorText = observable('Fehler aufgetreten');
                    this.name = observable('');
                }
                this.loginLoading.set(false);
            })
```

[Heres the error in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KE6L.png)

Comment: @Liam Its a node js express server

Comment: Well, are you seeing a network error or just in console? Are you seeing only the pre-flight request "OPTION"?

Comment: I guess this because of your backed server doesn't response for pre-flight request with headers to allow client server to send a POST request

Comment: @Liam It's just in console.

All pre-flight requests are handled here:
https://imgur.com/a/J2shF

Comment: @Liam But why I am facing this issue just in firefox?

Comment: It seems there's a difference on how browsers handling the requests. Firefox is making a preflight request which is a HTTP OPTIONS call, your code only answers to POST and GET so this will end up in a 404 error

Comment: You may need to clarify your content type in your request, added these to your axios headers if your data is JSON `'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

Comment: @Liam: None of the requests ends in a 404. The options handler as it is set works for all browsers just the way it should. The issue is that chrome, for example, sends an option request which firefox doesnt. Instead of sending the second options request, firefox denies the connection and results in the error that the server's response is empty (which it is because firefox never "asks" for the data to be sent in the first place)

Comment: Yes that's correct, as I said you need to clarify your Content-Type  and Accept on your client side and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` as true in your backend and `Access-Control-Request-Headers, 'X-CSRFToken, Origin, X-Custom-Header, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept'`

Comment: @Liam: Credentials are already set to true in the backend. Accept as well as Content-Type is set to "Application/json" on the frontend. Though also after adding the request headers (which weren't set before), the request/response behaviour is the same as before - the final options call misses and therefore the data is never sent and fails. Any other suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Add `Cache-Control: no-cache` to all your API calls

Comment: I've added it but still, no sign of working at any point. I believe, by now, that the error occurs because firefox possibly cuts the connection in the middle. I'm not quite sure, though since there are packets missing on the server-side plus as soon as the server receives the first thing, firefox's console already tells that the response is undefined with the connected network error.

Comment: That's right! I'm pretty sure if you're using Ajax jQuery call you'll not get this problem because Ajax doesn't send a pre-flight request, so if you still want to use Axios you need to check the headers in your backend and front end. I'll upvote your question hopefully someone else helps you though.

Comment: I know this was from over a year ago, but did you ever figure this out? Having exactly the same issue here.

Comment: @jacob Having the same issue. Switched to Ajax jQuery to not have this problem

Comment: @minus.273 If I remember correctly, setting `type="button"` on the button that was triggering the request caused it to work correctly, and I didn't have to switch to ajax jquery, although I don't totally understand why this works.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue with Firefox failing while all other browsers worked with my axios Post request. Sure enough, changing to type="button" from type="submit" on the button fixed it.  I'd love to know why.

Answer (score 2):

For others experiencing this issue, I can't speak to the pre-flight option stuff, but I do know that firefox is telling axios to kill the request. If you look at the section of axios that handles the error, you see the comment:

```
// Handle browser request cancellation (as opposed to a manual cancellation)
```

So it's some sort of browser quirk. I wasn't using a button to trigger the request, but an anchor tag `<a>`. It started working when I changed that to a `<span>` instead. Why, firefox?